# Does ARM Mali GPU has an abstraction layer independent of Linux kernel?

Tags: arm, mali

Before publishing its Videocore IV specification, Broadcom released an operating system independent binary blob. Does ARM Mali GPU has an abstraction layer independent of Linux kernel with an public interface specification?

Answer (score 2):

The Linux kernel driver is released as full source code; there is no kernel-side binary blob. Source code for the kernel modules can be found here:

- https://developer.arm.com/products/software/mali-drivers

... although silicon providers may provide customized releases for their chipsets (e.g. adding power management support), so ARM recommend getting the source via the chipset manufacturer. There is no non-Linux kernel driver available publicly to the best of my knowledge.

User-space library releases are binary only, available from the chipset manufacturer.